# Need assistance with 3NF decomposition

Tags: database-design, relational-database, functional-dependencies, third-normal-form

The relation R(A,B,C,D,E) has functional dependencies A -> B,C,D,E and BCD -> E

A is a key.
However, this relation is not in 3NF since BCD -> E is a violation, where E is not a prime attribute and BCD is not a superkey. So if we decompose the relation, do we get

R1(A,B,C,D) and R2(B,C,D,E) ? or am I incorrect in this decomposition

Comment: but isn't it the case that a functional dependency, such as A -> B violates 3NF if A is not a superkey and B is not a prime attribute? whereas BCNF is violated if when A -> B is a non-trivial dependency, A is not a superkey

Comment: Your decomposition is correct, the decomposition produces relations which are both in 3NF as well as in BCNF.

Comment: @CuriousPerson, A is a superkey because all keys are superkeys.

Answer (score -2):

Your decomposition is right but technically, you'd better introduce a third relation because the composite primary key is not a good practice at DBA viewpoint.

```
R1(A [PK], X)
R2(X [PK], B, C, D)
R3(X [PK], E)
```

Comment: Normalization to higher NFs does not introduce new columns. This is not normalization.

Comment: You clearly don't know what "normalization", "1NF" or "2NF" mean.